# Help needed for interpretation of mtry and MSE calculation for bagging and random forests

Tags: random-forest, mse, bagging

I have a question regarding the mtry values for the two models Bagging and Random Forests.
I applied the mtry measure for the California Housing Dataset and then for another dataset about white wine.
As you can see for the White Wine the pattern of MSE reduction is quite different than in the California Housing Dataset. A smaller mtry works better here, meaning that the predictors seem to be highly correlated. I put the MSE values for the different Models I conducted. But looking at the MSE values for bagging and random forests, they don't seem to make sense to me. Why is the difference so little when the plot of the Mtry's of the white wine data shows such a large reduction? And why is for 11 variables ( which should be equal to the bagging method, the MSE much higher ?)
I would highly appreciate your help!!!
[image: mtry for wine data]
mtry for wine data

[image: mtry for california housing data]
mtry for california housing data

[image: MSE values for California]
MSE values for California
[image: MSE values for white wine]
MSE values for white wine